# Using __kernel_vsyscall on x64 linux machine

Tags: assembly, linux, elf, x86-64

I am trying to use `__kernel_vsyscall` instead of `syscall`/`int 80` on linux x64.
I have read that it can be done on Intel chips (I have one), but i can't find how can one do it. I have x32 version:

```
int main() {
    __asm__(
    "               movl $1, %eax  \n"
    "               movl $42, %ebx \n"
    "               call *%gs:0x10 \n"
    );
}
```

One can compile & run it this way:

`% cc -m32 exit42.c -o x
% ./x; echo $?
42`

So, how can i call vdso syscalls on x64 without `syscall` and `int 80`?

Comment: It looks like it can't be done

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html